# Batch Random Name Generator

Tags: batch-file

I have a text document full of 1000 names, with one on each line. I would like to be able to set a variable to equal one of these names chosen randomly. How would I perform this? Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far, where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

A possible way is to count the number of lines of the text file, then to set the `skip` option of a [`for /F` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) dynamically and to read a single line only:

```cmd
for /F %%C in ('^< ".\textfile.txt" find /C /V ""') do set /A "COUNT=%%C"
if %COUNT% LEQ 0 (set /A "NUMBER=0") else (set /A "NUMBER=%RANDOM%%%%COUNT%")
if %NUMBER% LEQ 0 (set "SKIP=") else (set "SKIP=skip=%NUMBER%")
for /F "usebackq %SKIP% delims=" %%L in (".\textfile.txt") do (
    set "LINE=%%L"
    goto :CONT
)
:CONT
echo(%LINE%
```

Instead of `for /F` to read the line, you can also use [input redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-refirection.html):

```cmd
for /F %%C in ('^< ".\textfile.txt" find /C /V ""') do set /A "COUNT=%%C"
if %COUNT% LEQ 0 (set /A "NUMBER=0") else (set /A "NUMBER=%RANDOM%%%%COUNT%+1")
< ".\textfile.txt" (
    for /L %%I in (1,1,%NUMBER%) do (
        set "LINE=" & set /P LINE=""
    )
)
echo(%LINE%
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if this isn't strictly according to the rules, since you've provided a spec without showing any attempt to solve the problem,

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q44012305.txt"
:: detect number of entries in file
FOR /f %%a IN ('type "%filename1%"^|find /c /v ""') DO SET count=%%a
SET /a maxselect=(32767 / count) * count
:reselect
SET /a selection=%RANDOM%
IF %selection% geq %maxselect% GOTO reselect
SET /a selection=(selection %% count)+1
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=[]" %%a IN (
 'type "%filename1%"^|find /n /v ""'
 ) DO IF %%a==%selection% SET "selection=%%b"
ECHO %selection%

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q44012305.txt` containing some dummy data for my testing.

First, use `find` to count the number of lines in the file.

Since the random-number generator ranges from 0..32767, do some gymnastics with `maxselect` (the calculation is performed mechanically, not optimised) so that a maximum value for the RNG is established. For instance, if there are 1,000 lines in the file, a range of 0..32767 mod 1000 has slightly more chance of yielding 0..767 than of 768..999. By limiting the range to 0..31999, the odds of any particular choice are as linear as the RNG.

Once an appropriate selection is made in the range 1..`count`, re-read the file, this time using `find` to number each line in brackets. Since `delims` is the brackets, `%%a` will acquire the line number and `%%b` (since two tokens are selected, `1` and `*` and `%%b` succeeds the nominated `%%a`) will be set to the name on the corresponding line. When `%%a` matches `selection`, set `selection` to the name.

(That's just my history in assembly language taking over - re-using the variable since it has an appropriate name)